# Area Wise SKU Contribution

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with the following attributes:

```
Area    SKU     Volume
A       1       1
A       2       4
A       3       7
A       4       5
A       5       3
B       6       1
B       7       7
B       8       9
B       9       9
B       10      4
```

I want the area wise list of SKUs that contribute a specific percentage towards the total volume of that area.
The total volume of Area A is 20 and that of area B is 30. Let say, I want to see the SKU list whose contributing 60% of the volume in these areas, my output would look like this:

```
Area    SKU     Volume
A       3       7
A       4       5
B       8       9
B       9       9
```

The contribution of SKU 3 and 4 is 60% in area A, and the same goes for SKU 8 and 9 for area B.
I’m a newbie to Python so any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And why would that be the only possible combination adding up to 60%? I think you mean 60% taking the maximum value as a reference. Please make the question clearer and add an expected output

Comment: I would need SKU list contributing a specific percentage of total volume (in my case 60%). Output would look like this:
Area: A
SKU: 3,7,8,9
Contribution: 60%

Comment: As @yatu mentions above, you need to clarify your problem a bit more. The list may not be unique (is that a problem?), or no such list may even exist (what if an exact total for a given percentage does not exist? I can image it'd be difficult to get 52% for A, for example). Does an approximation suffice? And if so, over or under the given percentage?